# Padding around CCButton

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How do we create a CCButton with

- label
- stretchable background image

and then define the padding around the button?
I need to do this in code.
In Sprite Builder, there is "Horizontal padding" and "Vertical padding" settings for CCLabelTTF when it is a part of a CCButton. I can't find the corresponding properties in code.

Comment: Are you looking for `CCScale9Sprite`? I think you need to create a `CCButton` with the scale-9 background, then set `preferredSize` (as @Jonny recommends).

Comment: Yes, stretchable images are used, and probably required, for the background image states.

Answer (score 0):

The `preferredSize` property is the answer. Type is `CGSize`.

So this is what I do:

```
CCButton* buttonGo99 = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"99%" spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"ccbResources/ccbButtonNormal.png"] highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"ccbResources/ccbButtonHighlighted.png"] disabledSpriteFrame:nil];
buttonGo99.preferredSize = CGSizeMake(80, 75);
```